# here maps clustering is not accurate / unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have nine data points on a minimal example map.

The here maps clustering shows a correct cluster in a lower zoom level (9 items). When you zoom in further, the cluster gets resolved and the single markers get displayed.

However, this happens too early and the markers overlap each other (we have on cluster with 4, and one with 5 items, only one is visible).
I played around with all three clustering strategies and the eps parameter without success.

I set eps to 256 and get a reasonable result for this example with nine markers. With this setting, when I add more markers the clustering is quite useless because the cluters get resolved only at really high zoom levels.

Any ideas?

Please have a look at the fiddle I prepared:

http://jsfiddle.net/xv62430d/4

```
function startClustering(map) {

  var dataPoints = [];
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.53815990,13.41258410));
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.53815990,13.41258410));
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.53815990,13.41258410));
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.53815990,13.41258410));
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.47895150,13.45324740));
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.47895150,13.45324740));
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.47895150,13.45324740));
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.47895150,13.45324740));
  dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.47895150,13.45324740));

  // Create a clustering provider with custom options for clusterizing the input
  var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
  //clusteringOptions: {
      // Maximum radius of the neighbourhood
      //eps: 256,
      // minimum weight of points required to form a cluster
      //minWeight: 2
    //} 
  });

  var clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
  map.addLayer(clusteringLayer);
}


var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useHTTPS: true,
  useCIT: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Step 2: initialize a map
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), defaultLayers.normal.map, {
  center: new H.geo.Point(30.789, 33.790),
  zoom: 2
});


var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

startClustering(map);

$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not specifying the clustering strategy would default to the *FASTGRID* strategy. However in the *FASTGRID* strategy, the epsilon parameter (radius in which the algorithm should group points), must be a power of 2. Here is a link to the **[API reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-clustering-provider-clusteringoptions.html#h-clustering-provider-clusteringoptions__strategy)**. In addition, I think that *FASTGRID* does not recompute the clusters when you zoom in or out, that's why I would suggest looking into the *GRID / DYNAMICGRID* strategy.

I played around with your fiddle by uncommenting the clustering options, setting the strategy to `H.clustering.Provider.Strategy.GRID` and adjusting the epsilon parameter:

```
...

clusteringOptions: {
    strategy: H.clustering.Provider.Strategy.GRID,
    // Maximum radius of the neighbourhood
    eps: 30,
    // minimum weight of points required to form a cluster
    minWeight: 2
}

...
```

See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xv62430d/5/)**